# Send mail after user submit his post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

In my website users can submit posts through a normal form. 
My saved PHP variables are:

```
$usersarray = store the mail of the user
$postId = store the ID of the submitted post
```

The post submitted enter automatically in "*Draft*". 
I would like to automatically send a mail when his post becomes "*Published*", how can I do it?


Of course this have to work with different users and different posts submitted, not only the last one. (each user have his post submitted)

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `publish_post` hook which  is an action triggered whenever a post is updated and its new status is "publish".

> To  send an email via wp_mail() to the post author when their article
>   is published.

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Edit:

As @Stender have suggested in the comments below.

You could also use

`draft_to_publish` hook which will work perfect for what you require.

Comment: sidenote : `draft_to_publish` hook could be used, If he does not want to send the other posts. that way you can ignore `future, private, auto-draft, pending` posts etc. - but yeah - perfect way to do it

Comment: @Stender just to understand... I have to put `draft_to_publish` into `add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );` so it becomes  `add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );` ?

Comment: @Elle yes like that

Comment: yeah - throw it all into your `functions.php`

Comment: @Elle let us know? if the answer helped u accept the answer

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes it worked, I have to fix the author (is always the same, even if with another user) and the title, I can't see it. let me try :)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile all ok! I have used `get_post_field` instead of `get_the_author_meta`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile can I ask you last thing? I notice that the mail arrives also for published pages... can I limit this only with posts? Thanks